# Idiom to say "Clothes don't make the man"?

Tags: idiom

I was wondering if you have that idiom in German.

In French it is like "Clothes don't make the man", and in English it would more be "Don't judge a book by its cover", but I don't find some consistent things on the net about German.

Comment: Im Gegenteil, von einem deutschsprachigen stammt der Begriff "Kleider machen Leute" (womöglich aus einer anderen Sprache adaptiert), [https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleider_machen_Leute Gottfried Keller, Schweizerdeutscher]. Aber wir haben auch Sprüche für das Gegenteil, fällt mir nur jetzt spontan keiner ein.

Comment: Es gibt ein Sprichwort so ähnlich wie „Ein Anzug macht noch keinen Edelmann“.

Comment: @userunknown "Kleider machen keine Leute", also die Negation, gibt es inzwischen auch hier und da.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jetzt fällt mir doch eine Redewendung ein:

> Außen hui, innen pfui.

Und ähnlich ist auch das von Philipp genannte:

> Es ist nicht alles Gold was glänzt.

Sowie das von Pollitzer genannte:

> Der Schein trügt.

Comment: Vergleichbar: _»Es ist nicht alles Gold, was glänzt«_.

Comment: @Pollitzer Da warst du drei Minuten schneller als ich. Interessant ist die lange Reise, die dieses Sprichwort schon hinter sich hat: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/es_ist_nicht_alles_Gold,_was_gl%C3%A4nzt

Comment: @Marzipanherz: Ich halte das nur für eine halbe Antwort.

Comment: "Es ist nicht alles Gold was glänzt." ist dabei das einzige, das (wie der vom OP genannte Satz) offen lässt, was der tatsächliche "Wert" hinter dem Sichtbaren ist.

Comment: _»Außen hui, innen pfui«_ und _»Es ist nicht alles Gold, was glänzt«_ passen für Fälle _»außen gut, innen schlecht«_, während _»Clothes don't make the man«_, _»Don't judge a book by it's cover«_ und _»Der Schein trügt«_ auch für Fälle _»außen schlecht, innen gut«_ passen.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes we say

> [der Schein trügt](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/der_Schein_tr%C3%BCgt)

which is quite similar.

Answer (score 2):

Die wichtigen wurden wohl genannt. In lockerem Zusammenhang mit der Frage fallen mir noch ein

- *sich (nicht) von Äußerlichkeiten blenden lassen* - eine Standardformulierung
- *(nicht) (immer) nur vom Äußeren ausgehen* - ebenfalls gängig
- (Was (wirklich) zählt, sind) *die inneren Werte* (auf die kommt es an) - Gemeinplatz, auch ironisch
- *"Verlockend ist der äuß're Schein, der Weise dringet tiefer ein."* - Wilhelm-Busch-Zitat
- *große Klappe und nichts / nix dahinter* - eher allgemein für Angeberei
- der Begriff '*Statussymbol*' (Typ 'mein Haus, mein Boot, mein Auto')
- *mehr sein als scheinen* - als erstrebenswertes Lebensmotto

Comment: Lautet die letzte Wendung nicht überlichtweise: _mehr Schein als Sein_?

Comment: Das gibt es mit ziemlicher Sicherheit auch. Das "mehr sein als scheinen" ist ein Zitat, ein geflügeltes Wort, siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_gefl%C3%BCgelter_Worte/M#Mehr_sein_als_scheinen